# Insert a model with has_many association

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following models :

```
# Foo model
schema "foo" do
  field :name, :string
  has_many: :bars, App.Bar
end

# App model
schema "bar" do
  field :name, :string
  belongs_to: foo, App.Foo
end
```

And this form:

```
# form.html (Foo)
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
  <%= text_input f, :name, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Inside this form, how can I add text fields to populate my new `Foo` with `Bars`?

The following doesn't work because `bars` is not preloaded :

```
<%= text_input f, :bars, class: "form-control" %>
```

Am I on the right track ? If so how can I preload `Bars` in the form?

Update, controller :

```
def new(conn, _params) do
  changeset = %Foo{} |> Repo.preload(:bars) |> Foo.changeset
  render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
end

def create(conn, %{"foo" => foo_params}) do
  changeset = %Foo{} |> Repo.preload(:bars) |> Foo.changeset(foo_params)

  if changeset.valid? do
    Repo.insert!(changeset)

    conn
    |> put_flash(:info, "Foo created successfully.")
    |> redirect(to: foo_path(conn, :index))
  else
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end
end
```

The preloading seems to work, but I get an `Argument error` when reaching 
`<%= text_input f, :bars, class: "form-control" %>`:

```
[error] #PID<0.280.0> running App.Endpoint terminated
Server: 192.168.48.202:4000 (http)
Request: GET /
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (ArgumentError) argument error
        :erlang.bit_size([])
        (phoenix_html) lib/phoenix_html/tag.ex:66: anonymous fn/2 in Phoenix.HTML.Tag.tag_attrs/1
        (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1261: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
        (phoenix_html) lib/phoenix_html/tag.ex:35: Phoenix.HTML.Tag.tag/2
        (app) web/templates/foo/form.html.eex:16: anonymous fn/1 in App.FooView.form.html/1
        (phoenix_html) lib/phoenix_html/form.ex:181: Phoenix.HTML.Form.form_for/4
        (app) web/templates/foo/form.html.eex:1: App.FooView."form.html"/1
        (app) web/templates/foo/new.html.eex:3: App.FooView."new.html"/1
```

Comment: What does your controller look like? You could preload Bars into the Foo data there with something like ```foo = Foo |> Repo.get(id) |> Repo.preload([:bars])``` assuming you are using Ecto and this is to show a single Bar. Then use a for loop in the template to access each foo.bar

Comment: The action is #new/#create, not #show. Updated the question with the preloading of the `Bars`.

Comment: @Kernael, could you post the full error in your question?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Do you want to add multi `bars` when creating `foo`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out Jose's post on [Working with Associations and Embeds](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/) for a robust example using ToDoLists and ToDoItems (specifically the section titled **"Nested associations and embeds"**). The example below is a derivative example reflecting your combination of **Foos** with **Bars**.

To start off, you're on the right track with:
`has_many: :bars, App.Bar`

Modify your form to reflect:

```
# form.html (Foo)
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
  <%= text_input f, :name, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= inputs_for f, :bars, fn i -> %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= label i, :name, "Bar ##{i.index + 1}", class: "control-label" %>
      <%= text_input i, :name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
  <%= submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This utilizes the `inputs_for/4` function from `Phoenix.HTML.Form` to generate fields for your :bars association. Here we've labeled each sequentially, "Bar #1" and "Bar #2" as well as provided `text_input` tags for each.

Now, that you have to adjust your controller's `new` and `create` actions to reflect the inclusion of some bars (let's say two for example):

```
def new(conn, _params) do
  changeset = %Foo{} |> Foo.changeset(%Foo{bars: [%MyApp.Bar{}, %MyApp.Bar{}]})
  render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
end

def create(conn, %{"foo" => foo_params}) do
  changeset = %Foo{} |> Foo.changeset(foo_params)

  case Repo.insert(changeset) do

    conn
    |> put_flash(:info, "Foo created successfully.")
    |> redirect(to: foo_path(conn, :index))
  else
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end
end
```

Your `edit` and `update` actions will need to preload the bars:

```
foo = Repo.get!(Foo, id) |> Repo.preload(:bars)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your model has nested association you can use **inputs_for** to attach nested data to the form.  For example, please see [here](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html) in **Nested Inputs** Section.